# Rails4 Complicated Nested has_many :through, need help to find the "rails way"

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

My goal is to have users be able to nominate guests to speak about a topic, but the complication is that they (or user) can provide many "links" that will support this choice in nominating the guest.

So my tables, in their simplest form, look like this:

```
create_table "topics", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
end
create_table "guests", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
end
create_table "topic_guests", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "topic_id"
    t.integer  "guest_id"
    t.integer  "user_id" #(who nominated this guest)
end
create_table "links", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "topic_id"
    t.integer  "guest_id"
    t.string   "url"
end
```

I'm having a very hard time getting the links to work with a has_many :through, since the :through is the join table of another has_many :through (whew).

The adding of topics and guests is working great with this config:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :topic_guests, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :guests, :through => :topic_guests

end

class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topic_guests, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :topics, :through => :topic_guests
end
```

When it comes to adding links to nomiated guests, the link model is easy:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guest
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :user
end
```

But I can't seem to add links to nominated guests. The goal would be to do something like this (typing this out makes me realize why this is a difficult task to do in a "rails way")

```
@topic.guests.find(params[:guest_id]).links << current_user.links.build(link_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I'd really recommend that you sit down and really think about the relationships between the models. Sometimes it helps to draw out the database on paper to get a sense of how the models interact. There are a lot of ways you can restructure the data you have. Since it is actually somewhat complex, I'll lay out some options.

**Make your links polymorphic**

This seemed like the first one to jump out to me, you should make your links a polymorphic relationship. Here's a railscast (amazing resource) on it, http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised?view=asciicast.

With your model, you could set it up a few ways. For instance, the guests and users could have many links as polymorphic and the link always has a topic id. It depends on how you want to do the data.The migration and model would look something like this

```
class CreateLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :links do |t|
      t.references :authorable, index: true  # ex: user_id or guest_id
      t.string :authorable_type  # ex: user or guest

      t.references :topic, index: true

      t.string :url

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The models would look something like this,

link.rb

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :authorable, :polymorphic => true

  belongs_to :topic
end
```

topic.rb

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links, :as => :authorable
end
```

guest.rb

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links, :as => :authorable
end
```

This is just an example, you could have just had easily done it the reverse and said that links belong to users and make the whatever they are linking about polymorphic. This goes into my next point,

**You can make guests into users**

This isn't a requirement but it may help you out by removing guests all together and just making them a role of users. With just what youve provided here, I'd keep guests seperate for simplicity and use a has_many through relationship with guests and users with the inner table being called nominations.

The reason for the has many through is you may want to save data on that relationship, for instance it could have a boolean field called successful that is turned into true when he is successfully nominated. Here's a nice link explaining has many through, http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/1/15/basic-rails-association-cardinality.

**Has many through gives you a lot of flexibility here**

Now another reason in this particular example you might want to use has many through is that you can say the nominations belongs_to a topic and topics have_many nominations. I think that is an nice way of relating the data, but it really depends on the deeper interactions between the data that you will know better than me.

Are links only used in this app relating to nomniations and topics? And on that note, can guests only be nominated for one topic? Also can the links be used for multiple topics? These are all good questions you need to ask yourself. I can only make a recommendation but this assume things that you will know more about than me because you know the app better.

I could go on and on with how much an app works effects data structure, but heres my final connection between the data that I'd use:

1. Users have many guests through nominations
2. Guests have many users through nominations
3. nominations belong to a topic
4. topics have many nominations
5. nominations have many links
6. links belong to nominations
7. links are polymorphic with who created them (authorable in my example)

And I think that would adequately cover your problem. Good luck!